# Аналог for else в java

Tags: java, циклы, for, логика

Работаю с пайтоном, но возникла необходимость написать на джава. В пайтоне есть возможность использовать блок кода else после циклов, после успешного выполнения цикла

```
for i in range(0,10):
    # код цикла
else:
    # код после успешного выполнения цикла
```

Есть ли в джава реализация такого же алгоритма, **без введения дополнительной булевой переменной**? То есть если в цикле был вызван break, то код выполнять не нужно

Comment: Обратите внимание на цикл while do

Comment: Код после цикла выполниться и так. Если конечно в цикле не было ошибки. Этот блок по сути бесмысленен.

Comment: в java нет такого насколько я знаю

Comment: @Tsyklop в том то и суть что код for else не всегда выполняется, в отличии от кода который будет просто размещен после цикла (автор указал в вопросе зачем ему)

Comment: Хочется уточнить у автора, что он имеет ввиду под "удачным" и "неудачным" выполнением цикла

Comment: Удачное выполнение цикла - цикл полностью прошел все итерации, не было вызвано оператора break

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069402/efficient-implementation-for-python-for-else-loop-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оператора такого нет, но можно написать такое. Без дополнительной переменной

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // # код цикла

  if (!((i+1) < 10)) {
    // # код после успешного выполнения цикла
  }
}
```

Написал (i+1) для того чтобы вычислить следующий член итерации. Можно конечно проверить на i == 9 в данном случае. Но в общем с вещественными конечно нужно быть аккуратным на равенстве вещественных чисел

Comment: А почему не `if (i == 9)`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Наверно потому что так смысл этой идеи доходит яснее...

Comment: @AntonShchyrov конечно причин несколько, но основная я не люблю менять операции сравнения

Comment: Тогда уж константу вводить (вместо 10).

Answer (score 2):

чем то это напоминает такую экзотическую конструкцию:

```
someSpecialLoop: {
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     // код цикла
     if(/* условие "неуспешного" выполнения */)
       break someSpecialLoop;
  }

  // код после успешного выполнения цикла
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - вынести цикл в метод, вместо `break` в цикле использовать `return`.

Например, было:

```py
for i in range(10):
    if condition:
        break
else:
    on_success()

other_code()
```

Стало:

```py
def test():
    for i in range(10):
        if condition:
            return
    
    on_success()


test()
other_code()
```

---

Можно вместо `break` бросать исключение:

```java
try {
    for(int i; i < 10; i++) {
        if (condition) {
            throw new SomeException();
        }
    }
    onSuccess();
} catch (SomeException ex) {
    // 
}
```